# Upload image through custom/manual page process in oracle apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have created a form to upload the image. I want to insert the image to my table using the page process (not using the automatic DML process). How to achieve this in PL/SQL page process

I have added some code to insert image through page process but receving this error `ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEOPEN operation` .

See page 6

Environment:https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/

Workspace: shajin_wk

username: Test

pwd: Test@123

Comment: And ... why does the automatic DML process not work for you ?

Comment: Bcoz, I'm doing some data validations, so I have added my own custom code

Comment: Updated the question. I have added some code but getting some error

Comment: File upload has been around as long as I know. I have not seen another way of doing it. The file upload item has a couple of built-in validations (file type and file size). I'd suggest sticking with the existing functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload just a specific type of files(like .csv) then you can create a stored procedure that loops through the cells,then inserts values to the table(not the file itself). A very good example to that solution could be found [here](https://doyensys.com/blogs/xlsx-upload-in-apex-using-pl-sql/).

If your goal is to directly upload any kind of files, you should create a rest service for it. Follow this [video](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/upload-files-object-storage-from-oracle-apex-saipriya-thirvakadu?trk=read_related_article-card_title) to create and use one.